# Google App Script postMessage does not match recipient window's origin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-apps-script

I have a Google App Script deployed as a [Web application](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

It was working normally, until this evening I discovered it would not load in Firefox or Chrome.

In Firefox I am getting this message;

`Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided (‘https://n-...-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com’) does not match the recipient window’s origin (‘https://script.google.com’).`

*Removed part of URL*

The app is deployed: (Executing as *myself*, and is *Accessible for anyone, even anonymous*).

I thought the issue might be with LastPass as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919545/google-apps-script-not-working-in-chrome), but I have disabled LastPass in both browsers and the issue persists.

Comment: I'm seeing this also. This probably needs a issue raised in the issue tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but web apps starting in Chrome 60 may need to be set to `XFameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL`. I have a long running web app that just broke. Setting this worked.
[XFrame Options Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setXFrameOptionsMode%28XFrameOptionsMode%29)