# Google Script Web App: Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided does not match the recipient window’s origin

Tags: html, google-apps-script, iframe, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

First of all I checked already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014127/window-postmessage-to-script-google-com-as-popup), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833687/youtube-api-failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882594/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-target-origin-mismatch-http-vs-h/27911056), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563988/google-app-script-postmessage-does-not-match-recipient-windows-origin), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999718/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-using-apps-script), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573017/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-https-www-youtube-com-http) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194409/failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-domwindow-the-target-origin-provided-does). And they don't seem to be a duplicate of my problem exactly.

I have a web app, generated by Google Script. In my `Code.gs`, inside my `doGet(e)` function, I have a routing mechanism for handling different webpages, which I simplified below in a if else statement block. The `doGet(e)` returns different pages based on the URL, meaning, if the URL ends in `?v=page1` it returns `page1.html`, if it ends in `?v=about` it returns `about.html`, and so on. It all works fine if I type the whole thing in the Address URL space in the browser.

Now, my `home.html` has a menu with hyperlinks for those pages. The pages open fine if I click on the links, as long as the default target is `_top`.

Now, my problem is: I put an `iframe` below the menu so all the pages would open in the same home. They failed with error below:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: “SAMEORIGIN” from
>   “https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz80HBBQPcs-sYm9CsVNT7iyeBQjySR1FXN0TmgjKc/dev?v=page1”,
>   site does not permit cross-origin framing from
>   “https://n-72ap4753yyujkagtmqc7xoskf2cznnrfk23rzbq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/blank”.

I figured the reason would be the app was not published yet, so I publish the app and started returning `page1.html` with `.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)`. Now the error is:

> Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin
>   provided
>   (‘https://n-72ap4753yyujkagtmqc7xoskf2cznnrfk23rzbq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com’)
>   does not match the recipient window’s origin
>   (‘https://script.google.com’).

The error seems to be related to the page hitting another address in googleusercontent.com and that could be causing the issue?

**The home page:**
As you can see below in my `home.html`, there are 3 links:
**iframes** opens the wikipedia article about HTML/Iframes in the iframe of my `home.html`, just fine.
**Page1** should open my `page1.html` in my `home.html` `iframe` section, but that is where the error takes place.
**about** open the `about.html` as another page, on `_top` of everything, so it works fine. But as soon as the iframe issue is solved I will change the target for that one to open in the `iframe` as well.

My files are as below:

**Code.gs:**

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(e.parameters.v);
  if (e.parameters.v == "page1") {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page1").evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  } else if (e.parameters.v == "about") {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("about").evaluate();
  } else
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("home").evaluate();
}
```

**home.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
      #nav-wrapper {
        background-color: bisque;
        padding: 8px;
      }

      #img-logo {
        height: 2%;
        width: 2%
      }

      #nav {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
      }

      #nav > li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 24px 0 0;
      }

      #nav > li > a {
        padding: 8px;
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: 0;
      }

      #nav > li > a:link, a:visited {
        color: DarkSlateGray;
      }

      #nav > li > a:hover {
        background-color: GoldenRod;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 4px 4px grey;
      }

      #iframePages {
        width: 100%;
        height: 800px;
        overflow: scroll;
        border: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?
      var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
      var imgLogo = "https://png2.cleanpng.com/sh/e2fa53a06dccb65dbd183cfa6b13c455/L0KzQYm3VsIzN5dmj5H0aYP2gLBuTgRpbV5rfd9qbHWwcsPoif4ucKZyedC2YoLkebA0kP9tgZh0hp9xdX3kfn7vhfFlNaF0hOtwb37kfH75ifZtcZ9sRadrMnTkRoPsWPJkQJI2RqU8OEa3Q4q4UcUzQWg2UKU6OEW6Qoe1kP5o/kisspng-the-female-brain-human-brain-polygon-human-head-polygonal-rifling-5b2da62e8bc8a1.3386439115297183185726.png";
    ?>

    <script>
      var url=<?= url ?>;
      console.log(url);
    </script>

    <nav>
      <div id="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="<?= url ?>" class="brand-logo"><img id="img-logo" src="<?= imgLogo ?>"></a>
        <ul id="nav">
          <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames" target="iframePages">IFrames</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?= url ?>?v=page1" target="iframePages">Page1</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?= url ?>?v=about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <iframe id="iframePages" name="iframePages"></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```

**page1.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**about.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>About</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**the URL:**

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxBBaGG_rZl1jAuNqDzL8O9un7bfn9Qm_cfA_nAjMxE1w-dl2U/exec
```

Error image:
[image]

Error in the console. Frame on the left hand side is empty.

Please keep in mind this is a simplified version of my full app which is providing the same behavior so I could share.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: 1.Are you using `postMessage`? 2.Could you describe what happens when you click page1 link? 3. Have you republished a new version after `xframe` modifications?

Comment: @TheMaster, 1. I'm not entirely sure what `postMessage` really means. 2. Nothing happens on the home page, the iframe is still empty, but the console shows the message `Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided (‘https://n-72ap4753yyujkagtmqc7xoskf2cznnrfk23rzbq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com’) does not match the recipient window’s origin (‘https://script.google.com’).`. 3. I republished new versions after all the modifications, but I'm not sure either what the `xframe` you wrote is.

Comment: If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize. About `Page1 should open my page1.html in my home.html iframe section, but that is where the error takes place.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate this issue using your script. Also even when I tested it with your Web Apps, the issue cannot be replicated. So can I ask you about the method for replicating your issue? By the way, although this is not directly  related to your issue, `e.parameters.v` returns an array. So how about modifying to `e.parameter.v`?

Comment: @Tanaike I have the same issue: I can not replicate this with `page1.html`, however I recreated the web app on my test domain and added `target="iframePages"` to `<li><a href="<?= url ?>?v=about">About</a></li>` in `home.html`. Now, while I can not replicate this issue with `page1.html`, I can with `about.html`, though this goes away, when I add `.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)` to the `about` page evaluation in `code.gs`. OP, have you made sure that all templates being returned by your`doGet(e)` use `.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)`?

Comment: @Tanaike, e.parameters.v indeed was an array. I will take care of that, although it is working. About replicating, I thought it would happen to anyone. So, did you set it up and work for you? I'm attaching a picture of the issue.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, I was using .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL) for my Page 1 only, but I now add to About as well, but it didn't work either. The error is the same, as I just added a image in my original post.

Comment: @Rafa Guillermo Thank you for your comment. Also I think so. But I'm not sure that when the OP's issue cannot be replicated, the solution can resolve OP's issue. So at first, I asked the method for replicating OP's issue.

Comment: @Adriano_epifas Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested your deployed Web Apps, the Web Apps has no errors. "IFrames", "Page1" and "About" can be seen. Even when I tested your script in my environment, I could confirm that it works fine. So for example, when you changed the browser to Chrome, will the error be changed?

Comment: oh, this is so weird. I just tested in Chromium and it works fine there. It is only Firefox that is failing. Why is that?